# Can you select specific mods/addons to download or prioritize one over another?

Tags: steam, garrys-mod, steam-workshop

In Garry's Mod, I've subscribed to a whole bunch of addons from the Steam Workshop.
Naturally, if it was a few addons - I would just leave it running (since it would take only a minute or two to download).

However, I've subscribed to about 50 new [undownloaded] addons. Is there any way to prioritize which addons to download first or just pick (choose what to download) from a list of [all the addons you've subscribed to that haven't been downloaded/need updates] just like in the Source Filmmaker?

[image]

**A 'don't bother downloading [this] addon and skip to the next one on the list' command/button is good enough.**

EDIT: I've noticed that some addons are downloaded through the Steam client, while others are through the game itself (if it has assets, such as prop models or textures) from other addons or installed Source-powered games etc.)

Comment: its a long time since i started garry's mod but i think there was an option to change the Download order so you can tell him what to do first. But i'm saying this out of memmory, so it could be wrong.

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't a way to reorder downloads in Steam.  However, I don't have any Workshop games installed to actually test this for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As far as I can tell, you cannot priorities addons for now through the Steam Workshop**

*I have tried for games such as Portal 2 & Civilization 5, and there is no possible way to control there*

It is **possible** that this can be different in Garry's Mod, but unless the game controls the downloading of addons *through* the game itself, I would highly doubt, as it is up to Steam to download them for you. I do now own the game itself, so we would still need someone who ***owns*** the game to make a proper judgement though.

**TL;DR** If it is like most other games run by the Steam Workshop, then no, unless Garry's Mod controls the downloading of the addons in-game.